# Swift In App purchase crashes "message sent to deallocated instance"

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I've implemented an in app purchase into my app. It works intermittently.

Around 1/3 times it will crash, here is how I implemented it in an SKScene:

```
class GameOverMenu: SKScene, UIAlertViewDelegate, GKGameCenterControllerDelegate, SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver {


var activeProduct: SKProduct?



func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {

    for transaction in transactions {

        switch (transaction.transactionState) {

        case .purchased:
            SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
            print("Purchased")

        case .failed:
            SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
            print("Failed")
        default:
            break

        }
    }
}

func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {

    print("loaded products")

    for product in response.products {

        print("Product: \(product.productIdentifier), \(product.localizedTitle), \(product.price.floatValue)")


        activeProduct = product

    }
}

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {


    SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
    let productIdentifiers: Set<String> = ["gold_space_coins"]
    let productsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productIdentifiers)
    productsRequest.delegate = self
    productsRequest.start()

}

   if(atPoint(location) == buyCoins){

            if let activeProduct = activeProduct {

            print("Buying \(activeProduct.productIdentifier)")

            let payment = SKPayment(product: activeProduct)

                SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)

            }else{
            print("No product")
            }
        }
```

Here is the log when the crash happens:

```
loaded products
Product: gold_space_coins, 500 Pieces of Gold Coins, 0.99
```

Here I exited the scene then returned**

```
loaded products
Product: gold_space_coins, 500 Pieces of Gold Coins, 0.99
Buying gold_space_coins
warning: could not load any Objective-C class information. This will significantly reduce the quality of type information available.
```

It fails on line:

```
 SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)
```

Should I have implemented this in the view controller instead perhaps? Or have I done something else wrong?

Comment: That is just a warning from the debugger. What is the actual exception message you are seeing?

Comment: @Paulw11 It's showing "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=EXC_1386_GPFLT"

Comment: Something is probably nil. Have you set an exception breakpoint?  It doesn't seem likely that it would crash on the line you have shown.

Comment: @Paulw11 no breakpoints set. It seem to work when the app is launched. However if I begin game play and then return and click to purchase it then crashes?

Comment: No, you *need to set an exception breakpoint* to identify the line that is causing the crash

Comment: @Paulw11 When the app is loaded the IAP works fine. When I go to GameScene then go back to the scene with the IAP it crashes when I try to purchase. This is showing "message sent to deallocated instance 0x1016658f0" when I enable zombie objects

Comment: I think when I leave the scene I need to be removing something?

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED:

Upon leaving the scene I didn't remove the paymentQueue causing the memory problem when the scene came back into view.

This solved it:

```
override func willMove(from view: SKView) {



    SKPaymentQueue.default().remove(self)


}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

Swift 3

```
override func willMove(toParentViewController parent: UIViewController?) {
  SKPaymentQueue.default().remove(self)
}
```